How to run onnx finetuned llama model on groq. I completely stuck here
I converted a hugging face model to onnx and it is in static form, after conversion i want to run this model on groq. This where I am not understanding.
To run onnx we need to convert onnx to groq.
I am expecting to run my fine tuned model on groq lpu
